# Does meta tag in body section with itemprop and content work on SEO?

Tags: seo, html, microdata, meta-tags

I noticed that `<meta>` tags in body only works with `itemprop` set, but I have a question. Do search engines read its content?

Comment: *Which* search engines?

Comment: And which `meta` tag are you talking about?

Comment: I think OP is talking about Rich Snippets. Take a look at http://schema.org/ for more info if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: You have to think of SEO in a least two parts; PageRank and SERPs. Rich Snippets have nothing to do with SiteRank and Page Rank, but effect SERPs where they can effect the SERP format/appearance and CTR. Other than that, it does not weigh keywords more or less.

Comment: `<meta itemprop="priceRange" content="something here">` for example

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is referred to as "missing and implicit information".

Where the content you wish to mark up with microdata isn't displayed on page in such a way that you have existing markup on which to hang the microdata, you can attach it to `<meta>` elements instead.

A good example is VideoObject: a lot of the data you're providing, like duration or the preview image, aren't actually present in the page code.

This is documented on the Schema.org website [here](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing), and Google's support guide [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2413309?hl=en&ref_topic=4603851). And you can test implementations based on this with Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).